# Combining PhD and Work

Tags: phd, work-life-balance, working-time

I am starting my Ph.D. in Finance in November, This is not fully funded and I am considering taking a full-time job to enable me to fund my research work.

Is it possible to take a full-time or part-time non-academic job while doing PhD, considering the amount of time needed for research work and supervisor meetings?

Answer (score 1):

Whether it is possible or not depends you you and on the system itself. If there are required courses, then you need to be free to take them and do well. You need, in some systems, such as the US, to have the time for intensive study, not just research.

Some systems don't have time limits, others do. If you have to study at a slower pace then you might come up against time boundaries. In some systems there is a (perhaps) seven year limit. In some the limit isn't quite that strict, but things done longer than seven years ago no longer "count" toward a degree.

If you have a family or family responsibilities, it can be even harder.

You will also need a "compatible" advisor, but that is true of everyone. But they might need to accommodate odd hours.

Look at all of your options before getting into a no-win environment. Yes, it can be done, but only with great difficulty and lots of other sacrifice. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you're willing to do and how comfortable you want to be while doing it.

When I was in grad school, there was a fellow student who did her M.Sc. and Ph.D. - and excellent ones at that - while having two children along the way. She was very happy, if tired, and I admired - and still admire - her tenacity. She was a bit of a "fixture" in the department - I'm sure I wasn't the only one impressed by her determination. Sujatha, if you read this - you were my hero, for real, even if I didn't say anything at the time!

It is easier the younger you are. In my twenties I could pull off 4.5-hours-of-sleep nights for a week, while studying and working full time. Today? Nope, let someone else enjoy it :)

> Is it possible to take a full-time or part-time non-academic job while doing PhD

Yes, it is possible. Whether it's *enjoyable* or *fun* - that's up to you, your state of mind, and your health.

Answer (score 0):

It is 100% possible, since I (and countless others) have been doing exactly that. However, whether it is possible in your case, is a different question. It is difficult to say without knowing what university/country you want to study at, though finance is very likely among the most suitable fields for that.

Comment: Do you have some actual knowledge of finance doctoral study on which to base the last statement? It sounds facile.

Comment: Yes. You don't require lab or sought after equipment and you (in most cases) don't do experiment. Also, finance background is great for finding a well enough paid while collar job with ease.